# You are using deprecated Main class. Please use io.cucumber.core.cli.Main

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

While running `Feature` file getting this issue even I've tried by adding the dependence's multiple time by creating new `Project` but still issue persist

```
Sep 25, 2023 1:34:54 AM cucumber.api.cli.Main run
WARNING: You are using deprecated Main class. Please use io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
```

Dependencies:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>7.14.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.14.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>27.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Please provide more detail: version information and the dependencies you say you have tried.

Comment: Sep 28, 2023 2:40:23 AM cucumber.api.cli.Main run
WARNING: You are using deprecated Main class. Please use io.cucumber.core.cli.Main
      io.cucumber.core.exception.CompositeCucumberException: There were 2 exceptions. The details are in the stacktrace below.
 at io.cucumber.core.runtime.RethrowingThrowableCollector.getThrowable(RethrowingThrowableCollector.java:57)
 at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.getThrowable(CucumberExecutionContext.java:109)
 at io.cucumber.core.runtime.CucumberExecutionContext.finishTestRun(CucumberExecutionContext.java:104

Comment: Im, using these dependencies - <dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
    <version>7.14.0</version>
</dependency><dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
    <version>7.14.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>4.13.0</version>
</dependency><dependency>
    <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
    <artifactId>gherkin</artifactId>
    <version>27.0.0</version>
</dependency>

Answer (score 0):

Import **Main** using `io.cucumber.core.cli.Main` instead of `cucumber.api.cli.Main run` by which it is a deprecated class.